# Unable to see iCloud Music Library option in Music Settings

Tags: ipad, music, music.app

Both my husband and I have iPad Airs. Both of our iPads are currently on iOS 9.2.1 and it states the software is up to date.

For some reason in my husband's Settings under Music it does not show iCloud Music Library option, but it does on mine. I am able to do all sorts of playlists and add to them from Apple Music, but my husband is unable to.

Is there a way of getting this option? I have tried searching on google, but all I seem to get as response is switch the option on. How can I switch this option on, if it is nothere in the first place? Does anyone in here know what to do, to get this option?

Comment: Is there any way you could explain how to sign out of one and into the other, Isabelle?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever device it is that you don't have the "iCloud Music Library" option available to click on is logged into a different apple ID. I had this problem getting apple music on my Mac, I had signed up on my iphone. if it does work on one device, check in the settings and see what it says is the apple ID linked to the apple music account. I had been logged in under an old ID on my Mac's Itunes. I signed out and signed back in with my more recent ID from my phone and apple music turned on automatically, and the "iCloud Music Library" appeared in my preferences menu. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for the same answer when I came across your question and have also gone round in circles!  Nobody takes note of the third sentence of your third paragraph!  As you've had no reply I don't know if the following is any help.

I noticed a remark in passing on one website a comment which suggests that Settings > Music > Join Apple Music (it's in blue lettering) must be invoked to have the iCloud Music Library option appear.  I'm working with an iPod so the iPad Airs may be different.  Tapping it takes me to having to start a 3 month free trial to join the Apple streaming service - not something I would intend doing as I probably have all the music to which I can listen having everything from 78's to CD's and the odd download as part of my collection.

However, if you have elected for Apple Music on your iPad and your husband has not could that be the answer?  The problem may be nothing to do with this and my suggestion is a stab in the dark; with all the Apple experts out there being a complete novice I'm sure this will not be an answer.

Comment: Is this true? You need to join Apple Music in order to have iCloud Music Library option? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: iCloud Music Library is a paid service, so yes, you need a subscription to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my iPad and going crazy cause no information could be found online. You might have found the issue since the last post, but in case you haven't, here's what I was what seemed to be my issue:

On my iPad, I'd apparently signed into *one* iCloud account and *another* iTunes & App Store account. Once both accounts were the same, the iCloud Music Library "magically" appeared on my iPad.

Hope this helps!